# Как передать POST в сессию PHP

Tags: php, post, сессия

Всем привет. Пробовал разные методы для передачи. Проблема в том, что мне нужно конкретный параметр из формы только передать. И при этом сбросить, если были остальные. Остановился пока на этапе, "только передать параметр".

Пробовал данные сессии в функцию спрятать в зависимости от параметра формы, но это не работает. Можно и без TRUE, но это попытки.

```
session_start();
    
//unset($_SESSION['checkboxes1']); //пытался сбросить конкретный параметр =)


    
if (($_POST['checkboxes1'] == 1 && $_POST['checkboxes2'] == 2) == TRUE) {
    $_SESSION['checkboxes1'] = $_POST['checkboxes1'];
    $_SESSION['checkboxes2'] = $_POST['checkboxes2'];
    header("Location: index.php");

    
} elseif (($_POST['checkboxes1'] == 1) == TRUE) {
    $_SESSION['checkboxes1'] = $_POST['checkboxes1'];
    header("Location: index.php");

    
} elseif (($_POST['checkboxes2'] == 2) == TRUE) {
   $_SESSION['checkboxes2'] = $_POST['checkboxes2'];
    header("Location: index.php");

    
} else (($_POST['singlebutton'] == 3) == TRUE){
    $_SESSION['singlebutton'] = $_POST['singlebutton'];
    header("Location: index.php");

}
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.session-unset.php

Comment: А зачем проверка на == TRUE?